# Ruby console overwrites line when printing out lines in a file

Tags: ruby, console, loops, overwrite

I have started learning Ruby and I have come across an annoying problem. I have imported a text file into my program and I want to iterate over the lines in it and print them out to the screen.

When I do this, the console overwrites the last printed out line and writes the new one on top. Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Here is my code:

```
passwords = File.open('C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\pw.txt', 'r')
lines = passwords.gets

for line in lines
    puts line
end
```

Update:
The loop is acting very strange. I put a sleep statement into it and all it did was sleep once then continue to output the lines. I would have expected it to sleep before outputting each line. Example below:

```
passwords.each do |line|
    sleep 1
    puts line.chomp
end
```

Update 2:
I just created a new text file and typed some random stuff into it for testing and it works fine. Looks like the original file had some bad characters/encoding which messed up the printing to the console.

Comment: Start by isolating a reproduction with the fewest steps. Do you have to read a file? What if you just puts an array of strings? Remove extraneous steps.

Comment: @Rein Ok, that works with a normal array. Must be something to do with it being a file then.

Comment: as a comment, you shouldn't use the for-in loop in ruby. You'd want to do `lines.each do |line|`

Comment: What happens when you do this: `puts File.readlines('C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\pw.txt')`?

Comment: Could it be something to do with the Windows console? If it can't handle the fast output, maybe it overwrites the previous line.

Comment: Instead of making EVERYONE guess what your input lines look like, why not SHOW us?

Comment: It is a plain text file with roughly 30,000 lines of common passwords. I was going to make a password brute forcer if you were wondering.

Comment: Off topic, but ruby seems like a particularly bad core language for this. I say this as a ruby lover. The most performant cryptographic hash function brute forcers run natively on GPUs and would probably have at least two orders of magnitude better performance.

Comment: Also, this particular brute force attack sounds like a job for curl in a bash while loop, possibly forked for concurrency.

Comment: @mu is too short, I was think of something like `hexdump -c` or `od -c`

Comment: @Ryan, put a sample of your data into a file at https://gist.github.com/ or a similar site, so we can see it without any bytes being changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found out that the text file was the cause of my problem. I created a new one with the same content and it started working how I intended.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an EOL (AKA end-of-line) problem? Try this:

```
passwords = File.open('C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\pw.txt', 'r')
lines = passwords.gets
lines.each { |line| puts line.chomp }
passwords.close
```

The [`chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001188) call will strip off any `\n`, `\r`, or `\r\n` line endings, then `puts` will append the native EOL.

Comment: Let's not perpetuate the unnecessary use of `#gets` and the failure to close the file descriptor. Why not use `File.readlines`?

Comment: +1. Odds are good the line-endings need to be "normalized", which in this case means thrown away.

Comment: I like using `IO#foreach` to loop over the lines of a file.

Comment: @Tin Man, @Rein: I'm trying change as little as possible to avoid extra confusion. I'd normally wrap it all up in one open-and-iterate too.

Comment: @mu `%w(a b c).each { |x| puts x }` works normally and `lines.each { |line| puts line.inspect }` prints out the entire file normally without overwriting

Comment: @Ryan: Look at the `.inspect` output carefully. Any "^X" or "\X" (for some "X") things in there?

Answer (score 0):

```
File.open('C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\pw.txt') do |line|
  while not line.eof?
    puts line.readline.chomp
  end
end
```

or

```
File.read("file").each { |line| puts line.chomp }
```

Comment: The console is still overwriting.

Comment: This opens the file without closing it.

Comment: @Rein, in  block form,  it does.

Comment: That isn't `File.open` block form. The block is on `#each`. Try looking at `lsof` and see.